# How to change the default lookup entity when adding a connection

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

In Dynamics CRM, I have a custom entity that makes use of connections to establish relationships between the entity and some system entities such as contacts and users. When I try to add, for example, a contact as a connection, the lookup is showing a list of accounts. How do I change the lookup so that it shows a list of contacts and/or users instead of accounts?

Comment: You can try to have a look at pre-filters for lookups, but I wouldn't hold my breath that it works. I suppose MS is telling us that it's not needed to do this...

Comment: although I'm guessing you are referring to how to default the view, you can manually change the "look for" each time to contact/user.